# What JS objects are available in Qt Creator JS: variable expansion?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator's wizards and configuration settings supports [variable expansion](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-json.html#using-variables-in-wizards), including evaluation of JavaScript expressions, e.g. the [C++ class wizard file template](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/master/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/classes/cpp/file.cpp) contains:

```
%{JS: Cpp.openNamespaces('%{Class}')}
```

`Cpp` seems to be a global object. Where in the Qt Creator sources are those defined, and what's available?

These are not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 11):

The JavaScript variable expansion is performed by the [`JsExpander`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/coreplugin/jsexpander.cpp) in the core plugin. The expander can register `QObject` instances and expose them as properties of the global JS object.

To find all of those global objects, search for `registerQObjectForJs` method invocations. See the [github search results for this method](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/search?q=registerQObjectForJs).

As of Qt Creator 4.2.1, and until at least 4.6, the following are the only objects registered:

- `Util` - exposing [`Internal::UtilsJsExtension`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/coreplugin/corejsextensions.h),
- `Cpp` - exposing [`CppTools::Internal::CppToolsJsExtension`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/cpptools/cpptoolsjsextension.h),
- `Modeling` - exposing [`ModelEditor::Internal::JsExtension`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/modeleditor/jsextension.h),
- `QtSupport` - exposing [`QtSupport::CodeGenerator`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/qtsupport/codegenerator.h),
- `Vcs` - exposing [`VcsBase::Internal::VcsJsExtension`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/vcsbase/wizard/vcsjsextension.h).

The method parameter types are mapped to JavaScript types by `QJSEngine`. E.g. to obtain the Qt includes, one could have the following substitution:

```
%{JS: QtSupport.qtIncludes([ '%{Base}' ], [ '%{Base}' ])}
```

given the signature

```
QString qtIncludes(const QStringList &qt4, const QStringList &qt5)
```

The method list follows.

#### Util

```
QString toNativeSeparators(const QString &in) const;
QString fromNativeSeparators(const QString &in) const;

QString baseName(const QString &in) const;
QString fileName(const QString &in) const;
QString completeBaseName(const QString &in) const;
QString suffix(const QString &in) const;
QString completeSuffix(const QString &in) const;
QString path(const QString &in) const;
QString absoluteFilePath(const QString &in) const;

QString relativeFilePath(const QString &path, const QString &base) const;

// File checks:
bool exists(const QString &in) const;
bool isDirectory(const QString &in) const;
bool isFile(const QString &in) const;

// MimeDB:
QString preferredSuffix(const QString &mimetype) const;

// Generate filename:
QString fileName(const QString &path,
                             const QString &extension) const;

// Generate temporary file:
QString mktemp(const QString &pattern) const;

// Generate a ascii-only string:
QString asciify(const QString &input) const;
```

#### Cpp

```
// Generate header guard:
QString headerGuard(const QString &in) const;

// Fix the filename casing as configured in C++/File Naming:
QString fileName(const QString &path, const QString &extension) const;

// Work with classes:
QStringList namespaces(const QString &klass) const;
QString className(const QString &klass) const;
QString classToFileName(const QString &klass,
                                    const QString &extension) const;
QString classToHeaderGuard(const QString &klass, const QString &extension) const;
QString openNamespaces(const QString &klass) const;
QString closeNamespaces(const QString &klass) const;
```

#### Modeling

```
QString fileNameToElementName(const QString &file);
QString elementNameToFileName(const QString &element);
```

#### QtSupport

```
// Ui file related:
// Change the class name in a UI XML form
QString changeUiClassName(const QString &uiXml, const QString &newUiClassName);

QString uiClassName(const QString &uiXml);

// Generic Qt:
QString qtIncludes(const QStringList &qt4, const QStringList &qt5);
```

#### Vcs

```
bool isConfigured(const QString &vcsId) const;
QString displayName(const QString &vcsId) const;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also useful to note that several JS variables exposed via the macroexpander see:
https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/coreplugin/coreplugin.cpp#L169