# QT Creator wizard JSON - pre-defined standard values

Tags: json, qt-creator, wizard

There are many pre-defined standard values in QT Creator xml wizard,
documented here: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards-xml.html.
But they don't work in json wizards. Is there any replacement for them,
for example how can I replace %CurrentDate%  in json wizard?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that it is possible to calculate some of these values using javascript in wizard.json, for example:

```
"options":
    [ 
        { "key": "CurrentDate", "value": "%{JS: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()}" }

    ],
```

This may also help: [What JS objects are available in Qt Creator JS: variable expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763488/what-js-objects-are-available-in-qt-creator-js-variable-expansion)