# Where Qt Creator project build variables come from?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

On Qt Creator `Tools`>`Options`>`Build & Run`>`Default Build Properties` the `Default build directory`
has the value defined in terms of variables

```
../%{JS: Util.asciify("_build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}")}
```

which result in something like

```
_build-Project1-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug
```

1. From where those variables (CurrentProject:Name, CurrentKit:FileSystemName and CurrentBuild:Name) come from?
2. I would like to generate something different (shorter), perhaps like

   `_x86-debug` or `_x86d` or `_x64-debug` or `_x64d`

which variables should I look for?

Comment: I am searching for something like this, and I would like to add platform to that (win, mac, unix...). Did you come to any conclusion?

I think % variables like `CurrentRun:Env:<value>` could help, but I could not find the possible values for `<value>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the A->B button near the Reset button and above the tooltip that says "Insert Variable", you'll see a list of the global variables available in Qt Creator

[image: Qt Creator: Build & Run]

This is the same list, but easier to read:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/73762199051/

And this is the official docs for internal variables:
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-settings-environment.html#using-qt-creator-variables

You could do something like:
`../%{JS: Util.asciify("_x64-%{ActiveProjectBuildConfig:Type}")}`

Or you could set an environment variable with your architecture, be it x86 or x64, and do:
`../%{JS: Util.asciify("_%{Env:ARCH}-%{ActiveProjectBuildConfig:Type}")}`

---

JS is a special variable that enables expression evaluation.
This are the official docs:
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html#using-variables-in-wizards
This answer provides a list of the functions exposed by Qt Creator:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43763489/10996546

Comment: And where that `JS: Util.asciify` comes from, is it javascript?

Comment: It is possible to call some JS function that does split string?

Comment: @KcFnMi You can evaluate JS expressions, but I don't know if it is possible to split strings. I'm adding a couple of links to the answer about this

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options/Build & Run/General and it is there as "Default build directory".

Answer (score 1):

To see the list, follow these steps:

- Select menu **"Tools"** -> **"Options"**
- From the "Options" dialog, select **"Environment"** -> select tab **"External Tools"**
- Under **"Linguist"** -> select **"Update Translations (lupdate)"**
- On the right side, click on **"Arguments:"** editor -> click icon [image]

Now you will see all variables.

Note: Your problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970727/use-of-variables-like-builddir-in-qtcreator-kit-settings-in-qt5/35982389#35982389). I just summary the steps from the comments.